# The data is not rendered in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I hava some data to display the PH.

Everything is OK except I clicked `1小时` button.

Chart isn't render after this point at May 10, 17:04:21, which confused me half day.

Following is my demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/sknight/md1kcpgL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the `1小时` time range, every single data point is rendered. However, in your data, every other point is `null` near the end, so the chart never has two consecutive points to draw a line between. Your problem is better described in this question:

[highcharts with null data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790184/highcharts-with-null-data-points)

The solution is to tell the `series` to connect points even if there are `null` values in-between:

```
series: [{
    name: title,
    data: data.data,
    ...
    connectNulls: true,
    ...
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/md1kcpgL/18/